# adding, removing, then re-adding a custom method with Jquery Validate plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm having trouble with re-adding a custom method I created with the Jquery Validation plugin.
I posted a simple example on jsfiddle to show what my form basically does...
The user has a form where they pick a school from a text field (really an autocomplete).
The form has a custom rule so that the school_id which is set via a .blur event (in reality the autocomplete sets the school_id, but this suffices for a simple example).

Now they may switch to choosing the school from a regular dropdown/ if thats how they prefer to choose (via clicking a link). So i remove the school_id Validate rule, and add a Validation rule for the dropdown. But if the user switches back to the old one, I can't seem to re-add the custom autocomplete rule.

The specific part of code where i goof is here:

```
$("#school_autocomplete").rules("add", {
  school_id_required: "",
  messages: {
    required: "* Please type and pick a school"
  }
});
```

and here is a simple functional example:
http://jsfiddle.net/armyofda12mnkeys/4jsgQ/6/

Try going there^, then immediately clicking Submit, (you get an error, which is correct).
Then click 'Show DropDown', and click Submit (you get the newly added error, which is correct),
Then click 'Show Text (Autocomplete)', and click Submit. You now get a "Warning: No message defined for school_autocomplete", which is not correct.

Usually on that **school_id_required: ""** line, you'd have something like **required: true** or **"regex": "^some.+regex$"** i believe... but for a custom rule, it doesn't seem to be working correctly when i pass "", false/true,"blah" as a value to test. I saw an example where someone used something like           **school_id_required: ["someParam"]**, so i tried giving it a fake value to pass with an array to no avail as well.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this, This works for me, You will use the settings object and then assign new rules and messages :)

```
var settings = $("#school_autocomplete").validate().settings;

$.extend(settings, {
    rules: _Rules,
    messages: _Messages
});

var validated = $('#school_autocomplete').valid();
```

good luck with this.

Comment: I believe I got it working with some tinkering with your input (just used id of the form in the 'var settings' part instead). Thanks again! (although I wish .rules('add') would just 'work' like with non-custom rules):   http://jsfiddle.net/armyofda12mnkeys/4jsgQ/8/

Comment: I'm glad that you did managed to get this working. i did not try Rules.add, i will see the documentation, sometimes is very usefull.